# How can you open either a new browser tab or new browser window (shared session), in nightwatch?

Tags: javascript, selenium, automated-tests, nightwatch.js

I tried `.sendKeys('body', [client.keys.COMMAND+"t"])` and NW send the keys correctly, however a new tab has not opened.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `executeScript` to open a new instance of the driver, it will be opened as a new window.

```
JavascriptExecutor js;
if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
    js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
}
js.executeScript("window.open('/', '_blank')");
```

To ineract with the new window, you need to switch to it by:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  
    .windowHandles(function (myFunction) {
      let test_oldWindowTest = myFunction.value[0];
      let test_newWindowTest = myFunction.value[1];
      this.switchWindow(test_newWindowTest);
       to close or switchwindow
      this.closeWindowTest();
      this.switchWindow(test_oldWindowTest);
```